# What is the stance of this Stack regarding questions involving AI Art. from the perspective of an artist rather than a programmer?

Tags: discussion

I think that I probably already know the answer, but I'm going to ask anyway.

What is the stance of this stack regarding people (Specifically artists) asking questions about creating art using AI as a creative tool?

For example, someone asking about prompt crafting, or the limits of certain VAE, or how to achieve a specific type of effect. As opposed to asking about the AI itself from the technical perspective, or the perspective of a programmer?

"How do I do inpainting with X package"
"Why does my inpainting look weird with Y package"
"How do I replicate this (insert picture here) art style in package Z"

The AI equivalent of asking how to do something in Photoshop.

My reason for asking this is that AI art is currently considered out of scope on the Art stack unless it is part of the process of creating a tangible object, and it was suggested that a dedicated AI Art stack wouldn't be necessary as there was already a general purpose AI stack.

Comment: I am all onboard. So far this appears to be the single GPT-friendliest SE site. (Of course, wonder why, but it’s refreshing.)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think we would ever single out any particular application domain (I view art as one possible application domain for AI) as off-topic. Except probably if you get into illegal application domains. Anyway, art is not an issue here.

We do consider questions that are about how to do something with a specific package, framework, library, program, etc. as off-topic though.

> "How do I do inpainting with X package" "Why does my inpainting look weird with Y package" "How do I replicate this (insert picture here) art style in package Z"

So all of these example questions quoted above would be off-topic, because they are all about a specific X, Y, or Z.

More general questions about things like algorithms, loss functions, neural network architectures, objective functions, etc., that you could use to train an inpainting model would be on-topic. But specifically asking e.g. which line of code to write for inpainting in a specific package would be off-topic.

Comment: Wouldn't "What kind of 'prompt strategy' can be used to replicate an effect such as <picture> using AI art generators?" be off-topic?

Comment: @RobinvanHoorn I would currently lean towards saying yes, that's probably off-topic.

Comment: So, basically there would be little overlap if a new AI art stack were created because all questions relating to creating anything in a specific package would be off topic? Is there any way to get this as a specific official statement that could be used as part of a case for creating a new ai art stack?

Comment: @AaarghZombies I guess just a link to this particular Q&A would be fine.

Comment: @AaarghZombies For programming questions, you have Stack Overflow and Data Science SE.

Comment: @nbro, so, the consensus seems to be that questions on that topic should be fragmented and dispersed around existing stacks?